# Operand should contain 1 column(s) - Updating and Selecting with Case Statements

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to beat this error for hours without any luck.

```
  UPDATE `users` t1

SET t1.`Earnings`= (SELECT SUM(ROUND(t2.`vCost`,2)) AS totalEarned,
(
CASE 
   WHEN t2.`vPayment` = 'CreditCard' THEN t1.`Earnings` = (t1.`Earnings` * 1.05)
   WHEN t2.`vPayment` = 'Cash' THEN t1.`Earnings` = (t1.`Earnings` * 1.25)
END
) AS total

FROM `transactions` t2 WHERE t2.`ID` = t1.`ID` AND t2.payout != 'PAIDOUT')
```

Current Structure:

```
:::Transactions Table:::
ID,
UserID,
Cost

:::User Table:::
ID,
UserID,
Earnings
```

Result:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Current Code:

```
 UPDATE `users` u 
SET u.currentPayout = (SELECT SUM(ROUND(s.vCost,2)) AS totalEarned s
                       FROM transactions s
                       WHERE s.USERID = u.USERID AND s.payout != 'PAIDOUT'
```

The current code calculates it and saves it successfully, however, I want to implement vPayment as a factor in the query.

So if the vPayment is equal to Cash, then multiply it by 1.25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for (edit)?

```
UPDATE `users` u 
SET u.`Earnings` = (SELECT SUM(ROUND(s.vCost * IF(`vPayment` = 'Cash', 1.25, 1.05), 2)) 
                    FROM transactions s
                    WHERE s.USERID = u.USERID AND s.payout != 'PAIDOUT'
```

Comment: Yes, but it returns: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE t2.`payout` != 'PAIDOUT'' at line 10`

Comment: @FilipBusic I removed the `SELECT` (it was not syntactically correct). I 'm not sure about the logic though. It would be better if you included some sample data along with expected result.

Comment: I tried your updated solution but the result stays the same.. I'm trying to calculate the total of vCost for each user with the same ID on the users table as on the transactions table. Then I'm trying to set that calculated vCost to table 1s, Earnings. I've updated the question for more clarity.

Comment: Perfect! Works great, I appreciate your help. I guess that the first statement in the IF statement is true and second is false? 1.25 == true, 1.05 == false?

Comment: @FilipBusic Yes, exactly. This will work as long as `vPayment` takes only two values, namely 'Cash' and 'CreditCard'.